# Rails - Could not start web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm afraid I changed something in my Rails configuration, so I now get:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

I tried running the command, but get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
```

Thoughts?

I tried a few rake commands which I found in various support sites across the Internet, but none seemed to help...

Comment: you already have a users table in your DB and migration is trying to create that again

Comment: Ok, so how can I solve the conflict?

Comment: Just a hint: Cut and paste your `create_users.rb` migration file located in your `db/migrate directory` to another location(preferably on desktop) and try running that query again.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you could drop users table and regenerate it again? You could add **drop_table :users** inside users migration file